# could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = fireflyiii and table_name = migrations)

Tags: laravel, docker

I'm using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) for the first time to deploy a [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) application called [Firefly iii](https://firefly-iii.org/). I've created a server on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) from [their official Docker image](https://do.co/docker1804#start).

I just ran `docker-compose exec firefly_iii_app php artisan migrate --seed` - a step in the build process.

However, I'm getting a connection error of some kind:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = fireflyiii and table_name = migrations)


In PDOConnection.php line 50:

  could not find driver


In PDOConnection.php line 46:

  could not find driver
```

I don't understand why or how to debug it any further. According to the [Firefly documentation](https://docs.firefly-iii.org/en/latest/installation/docker.html#docker-hub-with-automatic-updates-via-run-pull) this is not something that should be occurring at this stage.

I have double checked the password in my YAML file to confirm it's correct.

https://gist.github.com/s3w47m88/e56431d58808180c9ff7e4ee962e03a6

Answer (score 5):

You should try this one: 
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this as well but it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is just because of MySQL connection not established.
Try to edit .env file to ensure the proper username, password and database name are in use. This will resolve your question.

Comment: I experimented with this numerous times and it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Docker. From this:

```
Pulling firefly_iii_db (postgres:10)...
```

Looks like you are using Postgres and not MySQL. From [Firefly III documentation about installation using Docker](https://docs.firefly-iii.org/en/latest/installation/docker.html):

> Firefly III assumes MySQL. If you use Postgres, add the following
>   environment variable to the command: DB_CONNECTION=pgsql

Comment: I noticed this, except all my configuration files say MySQL. And I didn't modify anything to tell it to use PostGres. But maybe this is a bug with the software. I'll report it and confirm. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Using docker, you need to switch your `DB_HOST` `.env` file from localhost to 0.0.0.0

```
DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
```